# REGEX PHP String to JSON Output

Tags: php, html, regex, json

i have an source code of an website (getting it from file_get_contents).

Looks so:

```
<td id=dat>
    2013-09-22
</td>
<td>
    <a href="http://www.test.at/results/show_results.php?v=12252" 
        target=_blank>bbbbbbb
    </a>
</td>
<td id=dat>
    2013-09-22
</td>
<td>
    <a href="http://www.test.at/results/show_results.php?v=12231" 
        target=_blank>Tlalalala
    </a>
</td>
<td id=dat>
    2013-09-22
</td>
<td>
    <a href="http://www.test.at/results/show_results.php?v=12234"
        target=_blank>Tzzzzz
    </a>
</td>
```

Now i need to do an regex so that i will have it like...

```
<?php

$JSON = array(
    "results" => array(
        array(
            "title" => "bbbbbbb",
            "url" => "http://www.test.at/results/show_results.php?v=12252",
            "date" => "2013-09-22"
        ),
        array(
            "title" => "Tlalalala",
            "url" => "http://www.test.at/results/show_results.php?v=12231",
            "date" => "2013-09-22"
        ),
        array(
            "title" => "Tzzzzz",
            "url" => "http://www.test.at/results/show_results.php?v=12234",
            "date" => "2013-09-22"
        ),
    ),
);

echo json_encode($JSON);

?>
```

Can someone help me ?

Comment: What were you able to extract so far? Where in the regex are you stuck? StackOverflow works best when we see what you've attempted so far. Also, please use code blocks to format your code.

Comment: Hi, i added the blocks for the code, and i dont know how to regex it. :(

Comment: Oh good! I didn't see it's HTML you're trying to work with initially. Parsing HTML with Regular expressions is generally not recommended unless you do it for a very limited and specific subset, even then - using an HTML parser is usually a lot easier and simpler. Would you accept an answer that does not involve Regular Expressions at all but rather use a (simpler IMO) html parser?

Answer (score 2):

Personally I would recommend using  html Dom parser and going about it that way - have a look at this one has some examples you can have a look at
http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/